# Unable to install iis manager on windows 8.1

Tags: iis

I get an error while trying to install IIS manager from "Turn on off windows features" on a windows 8 machine. Just before trying to install this I install Visual Studio community online and rebooted my machine. Visual Studio works fine.

I also made sure all updates are installed on my machine and also rebooted and tried installing IIS manager.

The error that I get is "The function attempted to use a name that is reserved for use by another transaction"

Thanks
Ranjith

Comment: superuser.com would be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 4):

Try to turn off your antivirus before install IIS.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the post! I'm running Windows 10 Pro build 10240

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent hours trying to find out the root cause. Tried to disable anti virus and other options as discussed in forums on the internet.

Here is how i resolved the problem.

Open up msconfig -> go to boot tab -> select Safe boot (Minimal) -> Apply -> Okay

[image]

Your machine should restart in safe mode and you should be able to successfully install IIS from the "Turn Windows Feature On/Off" section as described by others.

After the installation is complete, run msconfig again to unselected Safe boot so that you log in to the normal desktop environment on restart. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Just now i also faced that problem and this is how fixed the problem.

The reason can be another server which running on your pc, is using the same port as IIS. (e.g: 80 or 8080).

According to my solution, I started the wampserver. then click on wamp icon on the task bar. then opened the httpd.conf file from Apache.

find (ctrl+F) the "Listen 80" and replace it to "Listen 8080" or any other. save it.

restart your pc and try to install the IIS manager again.

hope it will works!!  Good luck.